# To prove that given subset is open.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

> Show that the set of rank two matrices in $ M_{2X3}($$R$$)$ is open.

Can someone explain, what kind of topology we are talking about here. I feel like $ M_{2X3}($$R$$)$ should be homeomorphic to $R^6$, but then can we claim that every basis of $ M_{2X3}($$R$$)$ will be homeomorphic to some open set of $R^6$

Answer (score 2):

The topology here is indeed the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^6$. To show that said set is open, I will give you a hint: a matrix $B \in M_{2 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ has rank $2$ if and only if a $(2 \times 2)$-minor is non-zero. A minor is a determinant of a submatrix. What can you say about the determinant as a function from the matrices to the reals?

Comment: Can we claim that all (2 X 2) minors will be non-zero or existence of only  one such minor is enough?  Determinant function is continuous & it will map rank 2 matrix to all non-zero reals? So, inverse image of R-{0} is precisely the rank 2 matrices. Am I correct?

Comment: @Aloknath Furr Just one minor is enough. Consider for example $(I_2 | 0)$, where $I_2$ is the $2 \times 2$-identity matrix.

Comment: @Aloknath Furr Concerning your second sentence: the determinant is only defined for square matrices. Hence, you need to consider all $2 \times 2$-minors. Can you construct a continuous function on $M_{2 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ such that the given set is the inverse image of an open?

Comment: Can't we claim that a function mapping all non-singular (2X2)  minors to its determinant value is continuous?

Comment: What do you mean by non-singular $2 \times 2$-minors?

Comment: Those with non-zero determinants. So, its image will be R-{0}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77266/discussion-between-aloknath-furr-and-p-senden).

Comment: For each $2 \times2$-minor the set of matrices where that minor is non-zero is open. E.g for the left minor we can see that set as $f^{-1}[\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}]$ where $f(a)  =a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12}$ which is just a polynomial in coordinate functions, hence continuous.